# How to accept multiple set of parameters in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make my batch file a bit more flexible.

Imagine a batch file that could accept multiple set of arguments.

So instead of doing,

```
myexe "path1" /s1 /s2 | myexe path2 | ...
```

One can just do,

```
myexe ["path1" /s1 /s2] [path2] [...]
```

So the first thing that came in my mind is to rename myexe to _myexe__ and create a batch file with the name myexe.bat.

Contents of `myexe.bat`:

```
@echo off

if "%1"=="" goto default

:start
_myexe__ %1
shift
if not "%1"=="" goto default
goto end

:default
_myexe__
:end
```

Now the first thing that would come to one's mind is to use double quotes,

But there's a catch here, what if one of the parameters use double quotes (eg. "path1" in the above example)

I would preferably use [ ] to make it look more cleaner and make my batch file smart enough to differentiate between single and multiple sets without explicitly defining it.

Is there some way to do it without using `%varname~:sI,eI%`?

Comment: Pass every argument doublequoted is the best way to deal with passed arguments. In that scenario, `%1`, `%2` etc. can be used exactly like that if you want to keep them doublequoted, or `%~1`, `%~2` etc. to use them with the enclosing doublequotes removed. To use `If` with them, as you have above, you can still use, `If "%~1"=="" GoTo help` and `If Not "%~1"=="" GoTo default`

Comment: Actually I am designing a batch file that might be used by others..So just wanted things to be more cleaner...[ ] would give it an unique look. I think I'll have to create my own .exe

Comment: Is there any way to replace double quotes with [ ] ?

Comment: Start your batch file by checking for 'all doublequoted' arguments, then if the end user doesn't fulfill the criteria, output a message to them explaining to the usage syntax, and exit. They'll have to learn, if they want to use it! And **no**, you cannot replace `"` and `"` with `[` and `]` respectively, because `[` and `]` are not capable of protecting any problematic characters contained within the passed arguments. Also please whatever you do, if you decide to use a batch file name matching that of any executable file in the current directory or `%PATH%`, always use their extensions!

Comment: Thanks @Compo. My problem is partially solved. Will I need to design my own program to implement the same logic using square brackets? Is there any way to achieve it purely using batch files?

Comment: There are two reasons to do it. One, the syntax should look more cleaner. Two, the batch file should be able to differentiate between multiple sets and a single set.

Comment: Of course you could write some code in your batch file to do it, but if you want it to be robust, don't expect it to be done without jumping through a lot of hoops, _(writing a lot more code than most people would consider worthwhile, and it certainly will not look more clean)_.

Comment: The solution I'd use for this goal is to process parameters using a for %%a in (%*) loop and then test the value of %%~a to determine if the parameter is a program, switch, or path  and act accordingly, with consideration (using result of prior testing) regarding the previous parameter.

Comment: Are you really piping the output of one myexe into another? Or are you simply sequentially running multiple instances, in which case you should have used `&` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe to parse arguments with a simple FOR because it will corrupt arguments containing `*` or `?` - it will assume you are looking for files and expand the argument into all files that match the wildcard mask.

I also share Compo's concern about naming your batch file myexe.bat, even if you rename myexe.exe to something else. Better to call your script something like myexeMulti.bat.

I always use a GOTO loop whenever I must reliably parse parameters and I don't have control over their content.

I suggest using a `+` parameter to separate each group of parameters.

The following is a robust solution that will always work provided:

- You never need to pass `+` as a parameter to myexe
- All parameters containing poison characters are quoted

Many times people test if there are any arguments by using `if "%~1" neq ""`, but that test will falsely treat `""` as no argument. I am being conservative and assuming you might want to pass `""` as an argument, so I test by `set arg=%1` and then testing if arg is defined.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "args="
:loop
set arg=%1
if defined arg (
  if .%1==.+ (
    myexe %args%
    set "args="
  ) else (
    set args=%args% %1
  )
  shift /1
  goto loop
)
myexe %args%
exit /b
```

If the user executes

```
myExeMulti /s1 /s2 "*" + + "abc" /s1 + "abc" /s1 /s2
```

then the script will execute

```
myexe  /s1 /s2 "*"
myexe
myexe  "abc" /s1
myexe  "abc" /s1 /s2
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always exactly three (3) parameters to the command, this can be used to process the groups sequentially. Replace `echo %1 %2 %3` with the program you want to run; `_myexe_ %1 %2 %3`. Please try it with your requirements for parameter groups.

```
ECHO OFF
SET /A "EXITCODE=0"

:head
IF NOT "%1" == "" (
    echo %1 %2 %3
    SET /A "EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"
    IF %EXITCODE% NEQ 0 (GOTO TheEnd)
    SHIFT & SHIFT & SHIFT
    GOTO Head
)

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

This script produces:

```
C:>CALL rotparms.bat 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Characters used in regex include: (from https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

```
backslash \
caret ^
dollar sign $
period or dot .
vertical bar or pipe symbol |
question mark ?
asterisk or star *
plus sign +
opening and closing parenthesis (
opening and closing square bracket [
opening and closing curly brace {
```

**Update:**

Processing the parameter sets using a `FOR` loop might work. The parameter groups must be bounded by QUOTATION MARK characters.

```
C:>type rotparms4.bat
@ECHO OFF
REM Invoke this by using a QUOTATION MARK character around parameter sets.
REM Eg: rotparms4.bat "1 2" "here and there" "when "we" get ready"
ECHO all = %*

FOR %%A in (%*) DO (
    ECHO parameters = %%~A
)

C:>CALL rotparms4.bat "1 2" "here and there" "when "we" get ready"
all = "1 2" "here and there" "when "we" get ready"
parameters = 1 2
parameters = here and there
parameters = when "we" get ready
```

Comment: I wish they were, but apparently they aren't.

Comment: If there are not always the same number of arguments to the program, then you will need to fall back to quoting the group of parameters, then parsing argv in whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes to group your sets and pseudo-quotes for the single parameters. First, split into sets, then convert the pseudo-quotes and split each set:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo all params: %*
set n=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
  set /a n+=1
  echo param !n!: %%~a
  set "params=%%~a"
  call :disassemble !params:'="!
)
goto :eof

:disassemble
echo all subparams: %*
set m=0
for %%b in (%*) do (
  set /a m+=1
  echo subparam !n!/!m!: %%~b
)
```

Input:

```
test.bat "'alpha' 'beta' 'delta'" "'gamma' 'with space'"
```

Output:

```
all params: "'alpha' 'beta' 'delta'" "'gamma' 'with space'"
param 1: 'alpha' 'beta' 'delta'
all subparams: "alpha" "beta" "delta"
subparam 1/1: alpha
subparam 1/2: beta
subparam 1/3: delta
param 2: 'gamma' 'with space'
all subparams: "gamma" "with space"
subparam 2/1: gamma
subparam 2/2: with space
```

Downside: your parameters can not contain `!` or `%` (`<>|&` are fine) or wildcard characters (`*`,`?`) (thanks, Dbenham)

Comment: This will also have problems if arguments contain * or ? due to use of simple FOR.